# Recorrer tabla dinámica y extraer inputs de cada fila con un botón, procesarlos con jquery y devolver resultado a otro input de la misma fila

Tags: javascript

Tengo una tabla dinámica y en cada fila que voy añadiendo, tengo varios inputs y un botón que llama a una función jquey con la cual, pretendo recoger los valores de los inputs de la fila seleccionada. Con los valores recogidos, creo un sencillo  código y pretendo devolver el resultado, a la tabla e insertarlo en el campo "código" de la misma fila origen seleccionada, de modo que; de la tabla, se debe de obtener un solo código por fila, de tal manera que si se editase posteriormente el valor de cualquier input, se genere otro código distinto para esa fila. El problema que tengo, es que puedo traer los valores de cada input y generar el código e incluso devolverlo a la fila, pero solo se inserta en la primera de ellas. Supongo, que habrá que generar un array con los datos de cada fila, pero lo he intentado de muchas formas y no doy con ello. Agradezco una ayuda.

DEJO EL CÓDIGO DEL SCRIPT

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function agregarFila(){
document.getElementById("tabla").insertRow(-1).innerHTML =
'<td><input id ="dia" name="dia[]" type = text></td><td><input id ="idplato" name="idplato[]" type = text></td><td><input id ="numplato" name="numplato[]" type = text></td><td><input readonly id ="codigo" name="codigo[]" type = text></td><td class="botton">coger valores de la fila</td>';
}

function eliminarFila(){

  var table1 = document.getElementById("tabla");
  var rowCount1 = table1.rows.length;
 
  if(rowCount1 <= 1)
    alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado'); 
  else
    table1.deleteRow(rowCount1 -1);
                       }

$(document).ready(function() {
    
   $(".botton").click(function() {
        // Obtenemos el valor de cada campo de la fila
             var vdia = document.getElementById("dia").value;
         var vidplato = document.getElementById("idplato").value;
             var vnumplato = document.getElementById("numplato").value;
   //    Obtención de la cadena del campo codigo
             var txt1 = "D";
             var txt2= "-";
             var txt3= "P";
             var txt4= "-";  
  
var vcodigo  =  txt1.concat(vdia,txt2,txt3,vnumplato,txt4,vidplato);
        // Devuelve el valor calculado al campo de la tabla 
          document.getElementById("codigo").value = vcodigo;
    
           });
    });
  </script>
```

AQUÍ LA TABLA DINÁMICA 
(He omitido el botón que valida y el envía el formulario a la B.D por irrelevante para la consulta)

```html
<html>
<form>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"  class="table" id="tabla"  >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>DIA</td>
            <td>ID PLATO</td>
            <td>NUM PLATO</td>
            <td>CODIGO PLATO</td>
            <td>Mantenimiento</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
          <td><input id ="dia" name="dia[]" type = text></td>
          <td><input id ="idplato" name="idplato[]" type = text></td>
          <td><input id ="numplato" name="numplato[]" type = text></td>
          <td><input readonly id ="codigo" name="codigo[]"  type = text></td>
          <td class="botton">coger valores de la fila</td>
        </tr>
        
      </table>
               <div class="form-group">
          <button type="button"  onclick="agregarFila()">Agregar Fila</button>
          <button type="button"  onclick="eliminarFila()">Eliminar Fila</button>
               </div>
      <br>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema con el **id** que estas capturando de los elementos, ya que al momento de agregar filas, el id jamás cambia. Por lo que, lo único que debes hacer es asignar un autoincremental a los *ids* de tus elementos.

```js
let count = 0

function agregarFila() {
  count += 1
  //alert(count)
  document.getElementById("tabla").insertRow(-1).innerHTML =
  `<td><input id ="dia${count}" name="dia[]" type = text></td><td><input id ="idplato${count}" name="idplato[]" type = text></td><td><input id ="numplato${count}" name="numplato[]" type = text></td><td><input readonly id ="codigo${count}" name="codigo[]" type = text></td><td><button type="button" class="botton" onClick="generateUid(${count})">coger valores de la fila</button>`;
}

function eliminarFila() {
  var table1 = document.getElementById("tabla");
  var rowCount1 = table1.rows.length;
 
  if(rowCount1 <= 1)
    alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado'); 
  else
    table1.deleteRow(rowCount1 -1);
}

function generateUid(id) {
     // Obtenemos el valor de cada campo de la fila
     var vdia = document.getElementById(`dia${id}`).value;
     var vidplato = document.getElementById(`idplato${id}`).value;
     var vnumplato = document.getElementById(`numplato${id}`).value;
    // Obtención de la cadena del campo codigo
     var txt1 = "D";
     var txt2= "-";
     var txt3= "P";
     var txt4= "-";  
  
     var vcodigo = txt1.concat(vdia,txt2,txt3,vnumplato,txt4,vidplato);
     //const vcodigo = `${txt1}${vdia}${txt2}${txt3}${vnumplato}${txt4}${vidplato}`
     // Devuelve el valor calculado al campo de la tabla 
     document.getElementById(`codigo${id}`).value = vcodigo;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"  class="table" id="tabla"  >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>DIA</td>
            <td>ID PLATO</td>
            <td>NUM PLATO</td>
            <td>CODIGO PLATO</td>
            <td>Mantenimiento</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
          <td><input id ="dia0" name="dia[]" type = text></td>
          <td><input id ="idplato0" name="idplato[]" type = text></td>
          <td><input id ="numplato0" name="numplato[]" type = text></td>
          <td><input readonly id ="codigo0" name="codigo[]"  type = text></td>
          <td><button type="button" class="botton" onClick="generateUid(0)">coger valores de la fila</button></td>
        </tr>
        
      </table>
               <div class="form-group">
          <button type="button"  onclick="agregarFila()">Agregar Fila</button>
          <button type="button"  onclick="eliminarFila()">Eliminar Fila</button>
               </div>
      <br>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Modifique la fila inicial con un `id = 0`, y los demás se van aumentando de acuerdo a si vas agregando filas.
Lo otro, es que cree una función `generateUid` que tiene el mismo código que tenías en el evento `click`. A dicha función le envío por parámetro el id del elemento y tu código hace el resto ;).

Nos comentas si te sirvió :)

Comment: He ejecutado el código en la web y me lanzaba unos errores en las comillas simples "  `  " por ejemplo aquí  ( `idplato${id}`) las cambie a  " ' " y listo, pero aun con esas no ejecuta el onClick="generateUid(0)" no hace absolutamente nada. Agrega y elimina las filas sin problemas pero ahora no entrega la variable `document.getElementById(`codigo${id}`).value = vcodigo;`  a ninguna fila. Si ejecuto tu solución directamente aquí mismo, funciona perfectamente pero no en la mi web, he comprobado hasta donde se y no veo el problema.

Comment: Si tuviste que cambiar la comilla, claro que no ejecutará nada porque no está tomando la variable *id* como tal. Muy raro que no te funcione en tu proyecto. Habría posibilidad que me compartas esa parte del proyecto?

Comment: Paulo, ya funciona !!! . Gracias crack.  Efectivamente eran las simples comillas. Curiosamente cambie la orientación de las comillas a la izquierda en lugar de a la derecha como tu ponías pensando que daba igual, pero evidentemente no es así. Una pregunta mas Paulo . ¿ Como seria...si en lugar de un botón por fila, se añadieran todos los códigos de una sola vez pulsando un solo botón al finalizar las filas ?.

Comment: Deberías añadir un botón al final de la tabla y cuando le des click, recorra los valores de tus campos, los concatene y los agregue a un array para después asignarlos en el campo código... Pero eso ya sería otra pregunta, si quieres formula otra y te ayudo con gusto 

Comment: Gracias Paulo. Lo intento yo y si acaso ya abro otra consulta. Cierro esta . Solucionado.

Comment: Si te ayudo, no olvides aceptar la respuesta. Feliz código!